# Passing arguments to threading. Arguments originate from input in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, infinite

I'm writing a script to run with a GUI.
There are two input fields and two buttonsץ I'm using `threading` so I can start and stop a loop with the buttons without having it freeze.
The inputs are necessary for some operations within the loop, I will simplify them as it's a very long `if` statement.

I've never done threading, the app worked before I tried to implement it.
The main question is how do I pass on the input from the GUI, to the thread?
It kept giving me `argument not defined` error.

Here's the code, any help is greatly appreciated:

```py
global x
global y

def scriptOne(x, y):
      print(x)
      print(y)

      while True:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('agree.png', confidence=0.85) != None:
             print("Here are x&y: ", x, y)
        else:
             time.sleep(2)
             print("Waiting")

threadx=  threading.Thread(target=scriptOne, args=(x, y))

root = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=(heightR*.2), width=(widthR*.2), bg="#26292c")
canvas.pack()
frame= tkinter.Frame(root, bg="#26292c")
frame.place(relx=.1, rely=.1, relwidth=.8, relheight=.8)

xEntry=tkinter.Entry(frame, bg='#c5c7c4')
xEntry.place(relx=.4, rely=.05, relwidth=.75, relheight=.15)

yEntry=tkinter.Entry(frame, bg='#c5c7c4')
yEntry.place(relx=.4, rely=.3, relwidth=.75, relheight=.15)

labelX = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Pick", padx=1, pady=1, fg="white", bg="#26292c")
labelX.place(relx=0, rely=.05, relwidth=.25, relheight=.15)

labelY = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Ban", padx=1, pady=1, fg="white", bg="#26292c")
labelY.place(relx=0, rely=.3, relwidth=.25, relheight=.15)

startScript=tkinter.Button(frame, text="Activate Script", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#52595d", command= lambda: threadx.start(xEntry.get(),yEntry.get()))
startScript.place(relx=.05, rely=.8, relwidth=.4, relheight=.2)

endScript=tkinter.Button(frame, text="Quit Script", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#52595d", command=exit)
endScript.place(relx=.55, rely=.8, relwidth=.4, relheight=.2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your `x` and `y`, its undefined in the example you gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better create another function to create the `Thread` instance and start it:

```
def start_thread():
    # make sure x and y are input correctly
    try:
        x = int(xEntry.get().strip())
        y = int(yEntry.get().strip())
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid x or y value')
        return

    # disable the button which is associated with this function
    startScript.config(state='disabled')

    # create thread and start it
    threading.Thread(target=scriptOne, args=(x,y), daemon=True).start()
```

Then assign the above function to `startScript` button:

```
startScript = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Activate Script", padx=10, pady=5,
                             fg="white", bg="#52595d", command=start_thread)
```